# How to print the value of `T.dot(l3,w)`, python

Tags: python, theano

`l3` and `w` are `4D`-matrics with the shape of `(16,1,28,28)`. We are using [Theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/). The question is how we can print the value of `T.dot(l3,w)`? Once I run the command, it gives me:`dot.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`l3` and `w` seems to be **theano tensor variables** which are **symbolic** and contains no value. Only the **type**(integer or float) and the **dimensions**(4D) are specified yet. Once you execute

```
import theano.tensor as T
result = T.dot(l3,w)
```

`result` also is a theano tensor variable, and hence it is symbolic. By far, no real inner product calculation has been performed. Only the symbolic representation of result has been determined. You need to execute further codes to make actual calculation take in place.

```
from theano import function
foo = function([l3,w], result) #takes some time
value = foo(value_of_l3, value_of_w) #value is now calculated.
```

The methods `function` returns a function object that calculates `result` from given `l3` and `w`.